# Internet through Wi-Fi works only on one of the connected devices

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

I am using a DSL router that has modem and router in one unit. All of my devices are able to connect to the Wi-Fi but internet only works on only one of them (no bias towards any of the devices). Generally this is  the device  that connected to the Wi-Fi first. I have reset the system several times but the problem persists. An additional problem that comes up is if my laptop is connected to Wi-Fi and using internet, then my phones ask me to sign-in to Wi-Fi whenever I connect to it. Mostly, it doesn't sign-in and I give up and use cellular data.
As a trial, I deactivated WLAN on this router and connected a wireless router (only router, the kind that connects to a cable modem) to use as the Wi-Fi access point but the problem still persists.
Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: Make sure all your devices are configured to obtain IP and DNS automatically. It may be that you have one or more IP address conflicts...

Answer (score 0):

(Please give more details - about your DSL modem model etc)

Try chaning your Wi-Fi channel.
I have experienced this issue earlier, and it was my wireless channel number that caused interference with other WiFis around it.

Change your wireless channel to 1, 6 or 11 (which are totally non interfering channels). It may solve your issue.

Comment: I have already tried changing the channel but it doesn't work. I did it again and  still nothing. What details do you need for the modem?

Comment: I mean, I need the brand and the model number. Is your DHCP server turned on in your modem router?

Comment: Its a Teracom TDSL300W2. DHCP is on. Simply said internet always works on laptop. phones can connect during this time but either its always stuck at sign-in to wifi network or it signs in but internet will never work. If I disconnect my laptop, then it will work on phone (maybe phones sometimes). This link will give you a look on the setup page for this modem: http://www.netvuze.com/2013/04/dsl-broadband-modem-configuration.html.

Comment: 1. Seems like you use BSNL ADSL broadband. What is the MTU set in the router? Set as 1458 and restart the modem router.
2. Try resetting the modem router.